# SetText on Object not working for Calendar

Tags: java, android, date

So I'm using the following Java library: [UmmalquraCalendar](https://github.com/msarhan/ummalqura-calendar)

I am using `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` to parse Ummalqura date.

MainActivity `onCreate` method taken from the library `README.md` file:

```
Locale en = Locale.ENGLISH;
UmmalquraCalendar uCal = new UmmalquraCalendar(en);

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("", en);
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
dateFormat.setCalendar(uCal);
uCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1420);
dateFormat.set2DigitYearStart(uCal.getTime());

Calendar cal = new UmmalquraCalendar(en);

dateFormat.applyPattern("d/M/y");
cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, en);
cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

My understanding is `cal` is an object so to display this in a `TextView` using `setText`, I would need to convert it to a string so I added the following to my code:

```
String islamicDate = cal.toString();
layoutDate.setText(islamicDate);
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image: output]

Can someone please help me understand where I am going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your are setting your `textview` with the hole object , try this :

```
String year = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
String month = String.valueOf(cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, en));
String day = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
layoutDate.setText(year + "-" + month +"-" + day);
```